# 413 - request entity too large in lighthttpd

Tags: lighttpd, php.ini

When saving configuration settings in Magento I get "413 - request entity too large". We are running lighttpd.

In php.ini `memory_limit = -1`

In lighttpd.conf `server.max-request-size = 1000000`

I have restarted lighttpd and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

What is `post_max_size` in `php.ini`? This controls how much data php will accept. I suspect it is set too low for your situation.

The default is 8M. Try `post_max_size = 25M` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. Thing is that this is text being posted. So it shouldn't be that heavy.

Answer (score 0):

There was a regression in 1.4.36, which should be fixed in 1.4.37: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2660 (another regression related to not existing upload directory was fixed in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/revisions/3046, not released yet)